# parsley.js global settings

Tags: jquery, parsley.js

I am using the below parsley validator on multiple form fields to exclude percent signs.

```
data-validation="alphanumeric" data-validation-allowing="-_~`!@#$^&*()_+-  =:;'<,>.?/{}\[\]\\| &quot;" data-validation-error-msg="percent signs (%) not allowed"
```

To avoid repeating this many times for each field, How would I configure parsley to have the above global setting?

Answer (score 0):

`data-validation-allowing` doesn't seem to correspond to anything to do with `Parsley`.

If it did, you could modify `Parsley.options.allowing = '...'`, as explained in [the doc](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-usage-configuration), sections "Option inheritance" and "naming".

HTH

Comment: Cheers, although no further info found on web RE: Parsley.options.validationAllowing

Comment: I assumed your initial setting made sense... Answer edited.